# why sometime google play library is not detecting the latest build

Tags: android, google-play, android-build, in-app-update

I am using [in app update](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates) some time it's working fine but some time not like yesterday it's detecting perfectly for new update but today it's not detecting the new update on play Store I implemented as same as they have suggested in document. Is there anything else I have to add to avoid this situation and I also take care of these [situation](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates#troubleshoot) and I am testing or updating new build in close group for testers on play store and in my play store app i am sign-in with same account i gave in tester group

**Edit**

Even in play store it's showing open instead of update what i did first posted the app with version code 12 on play store then change the version code to 11 and try to test the app but it's not working any body know why?

Answer (score 0):

even if You go to the app page in play store and see there is an update available, then also google play doesn't detect it. But if you go to "My apps & games" from the side menu, then it detects and shows update of the app there, then it will detect in your app as In-App update, I am also very irritated by this, what a shitty implementation.

If an used goes all the way to the "My apps & games" page then he or she would update from there, the In-app update API should detect latest update flawlessly , user shouldn't have to go to any page in play store for the API to detect update.